# Filter data before sending it to a subscriber (NServiceBus)

Tags: c#, .net, soa, nservicebus, servicebus

I Have many clients which needs to be notified when new data is added to one of our DB tables.
I Think about creating a service which checks the table every X seconds and notifies the clients if any new data exists. The problem is, each client have different permissions and is not allowed to see all the information. I thought about using something like NServiceBus to publish the message with the new information, but I need to filter the information according to each client's permissions before sending it. The filtering needs to be done before sending the info (I'm not allowed to perform the filtering on the client side).

Is there a built-in support for this in NServiceBus?

If not, How can I achieve this goal?

**EDIT:**
Here is an example I wrote in the comment below:
say I have a book library. Each client is interested in receiving *immediate* notification about new books added to the library, but each client is allowed to be notified only about a certain genre. The system should send a notification to all the clients containing the new books information, but each client should only be notified about his specific genre. For security reasons, I can't filter the data in the client.

Thanks.

Comment: Are there groups of clients that are interested in similar data?  Or is each client looking for a different set?  Are the clients and the data part of the same Business Component(Marketing vs. Billing)?

Comment: all the clients should recieve a subset of the data added to the table, according to their group in the AD. There is no difference between the clients other than that. 
I'll try to be more specific: each entity which is added to the table has a group property, and each client is only allowed to see some of the groups.

Comment: For example: say I have a book library. Each client is interested in receiving *immediate* notification about new books added to the library, but each client is allowed to be notified only about a certain genre. The system should send a notification to all the clients containing the new books information, but each client should only be notified about his specific genre. For security reasons, I can't filter the data in the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A potential option would be to only allow certain clients to subscribe to genres they are allowed to see.  NSB provides the IAuthorizeSubscriptions interface to allow you to determine who is allowed to subscribe to a message.  By splitting up the messages by genre you could then allow/deny subscription to those genres by using the authorization interface.

Comment: Thanks for the comment...
I thought about this option, but the problem is that the "genres" are dynamic and can be added/removed on the fly.

Comment: I'm thinking you will have to mimic the publish functionality and dispatch(Bus.Send()) based on your custom criteria(essentially a message inspector).  You could wrap this up into a base class for convenience.

Comment: You would use the same approach as NSB, query the storage(usually the DB with a single table).  They can all subscribe to the same message, you'll just have to filter it out on your own up front.

Comment: I understand what you say, but I can't seem to find how to query the suscribers storage (unless you are talking about quering it with without using the framework). Can you please give a code example?

Comment: Sure, you can use the framework, just ask the container for an instance of ISubscriptionStorage with something like s = Bus.Builder.Build<ISubscriptionStorage>().  Then you can call s.GetSubscribersForMessage()...